# TradingView widget adding Label to a point with PineScript

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Hello Everyone i am building a Trading Signal panel using TradingView into a web project and i wish to Add a Label/Tag on the last point where the market price was before a button was clicked,

now i must explain

for Example am using TradingView and now how do i add a Stylish Label/Tag/Indicator at the point where the Market price was before a button was clicked??

I am using Javascript and i have read very far and i got nothing yet

`new TradingView.widget(
            {
                "autosize": true,
                "symbol": "FX:EURUSD",
                "interval": "1",
                "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
                "theme": "Dark",
                "style": "1",
                "locale": "en",
                "toolbar_bg": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
                "enable_publishing": false,
                "allow_symbol_change": true,
                "container_id": "crypt-candle-chart"
            }
        );`

I have read about PINE Script but how do i use the pinescript with my Javascript code? Bolow is example PINE Script

```
$('#button-stake').click(function(){
  //@version=3
  study("Bitfinex BTC margin position differences", shorttitle="BitFinex positions differences")


 long = security("BITFINEX:BTCUSDLONGS", period, close)
 short = security("BITFINEX:BTCUSDSHORTS", period, close)

 longDEF = long-short
shortDEF = short-long


 plot(longDEF, style=line, color=green)
plot(shortDEF, style=line, color=red)

});
```

All my tries returns Error and nothing will load please i need this seriously i have spent over 2 months trying this but nothing came out. I am using PHP + JS

IF YOU SEE BELOW IMAGE YOU WILL UNDERSTAND THE LABEL I AM TALKING OF

[image: BELOW IS EXAMPLE OF THE LABEL I MEANT]

[image: IMAGE WITH PRICE REFERENCE]

Comment: Please anyone who can help me? i knows nothing about this.